# Theme of app doesn't change dynamically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the theme or color of the app when the user selects an option from an `AlertDialog`. I made the same technique for changing the size of font, and it's works fine. I don't what is the mistake I made for changing the color.

**strings.xml:**

```
    <resources>

<string-array name="font_sizes">
        <item>14</item>
        <item>16</item>
        <item>18</item>
        <item>20</item>
        <item>22</item>
    </string-array>

            <string-array name="app_colors">
                <item>0</item>
                <item>1</item>
                <item>2</item>
                <item>3</item>
                <item>4</item>
            </string-array>

        </resources>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <style name="BlackTheme">
            <item name="colorPrimary">#FF000000</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF000000</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">#FF000000</item>
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#FF000000</item>
        </style>

        <style name="BlueTheme">
            <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000FF</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF0000FF</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000FF</item>
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#FF0000FF</item>
        </style>

        <style name="GreenTheme">
            <item name="colorPrimary">#008000</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#008000</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">#008000</item>
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#008000</item>
        </style>

        <style name="MagentaTheme">
            <item name="colorPrimary">#D500F9</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#D500F9</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">#D500F9</item>
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#D500F9</item>
        </style>

    </resources>
```

**PreferencesActivity.java:**

```
package sa.edu.qu.coc.cocapps.prefs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import sa.edu.qu.coc.cocapps.R;

public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar = null;
    public static final String PREFS_KEY = "preferences";
    private static int item = 0, color = 0;
    private LinearLayout fontSize;
    private LinearLayout appColor;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        initViews();

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fontSize.setOnClickListener(this);
        appColor.setOnClickListener(this);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        fontSize = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fontSize);
        appColor = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.appColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.fontSize:
                AlertDialog.Builder changeFontSizeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Select Size")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat)
                        .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.font_sizes, item, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                editor = prefs.edit();
                                editor.putInt("fontSize", i);
                                editor.commit();

                                item = i;
                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                // DO not do anything.
                            }
                        });
                changeFontSizeDialog.show();
                break;

            case R.id.appColor:
                AlertDialog.Builder changeAppColorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Select color")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat)
                        .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.app_colors, color, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                editor = prefs.edit();
                                editor.putInt("appColor", which);
                                editor.commit();

                                color = which;
                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                // DO not do anything.
                            }
                        });
                changeAppColorDialog.show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        switch(prefs.getInt("appColor", 0))
        {
            case 0:
                this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                return;

            case 1:
                this.setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
                return;

            case 2:
                this.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
                return;

            case 3:
                this.setTheme(R.style.GreenTheme);
                return;

            case 4:
                this.setTheme(R.style.MagentaTheme);
                return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the activity has to be restarted for the theme to be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The following code is the whole solution.

**strings.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="font_sizes">
        <item>14</item>
        <item>16</item>
        <item>18</item>
        <item>20</item>
        <item>22</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="app_colors">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

**styles.xml: (Also, do not forget to add the same custom styles to styles.xml (v21)):**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="BlackTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#FF000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BlueTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000FF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF0000FF</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000FF</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#FF0000FF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GreenTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#008000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#008000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#008000</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#008000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MagentaTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#D500F9</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#D500F9</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#D500F9</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#D500F9</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**PreferencesActivity.java:**

```
package sa.edu.qu.coc.cocapps.prefs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import sa.edu.qu.coc.cocapps.R;

public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar = null;
    private LinearLayout fontSize, appColor;
    public static final String PREFS_KEY = "preferences";
    private static int item = 0, color = 0;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = this;
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        switch(prefs.getInt("appColor", 0)) {
            case 0:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                break;

            case 1:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
                break;

            case 2:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
                break;

            case 3:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.GreenTheme);
                break;

            case 4:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.MagentaTheme);
                break;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

        initViews();

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fontSize.setOnClickListener(this);
        appColor.setOnClickListener(this);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        fontSize = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fontSize);
        appColor = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.appColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.fontSize:
                AlertDialog.Builder changeFontSizeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Select Size")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat)
                        .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.font_sizes, item, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                editor = prefs.edit();
                                editor.putInt("fontSize", i);
                                editor.commit();

                                item = i;
                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                // DO not do anything.
                            }
                        });
                changeFontSizeDialog.show();
                break;

            case R.id.appColor:
                AlertDialog.Builder changeAppColorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Select Color")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat)
                        .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.app_colors, color, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                editor = prefs.edit();
                                editor.putInt("appColor", i);
                                editor.commit();

                                color = i;

                                activity.finish();
                                activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                // DO not do anything.
                            }
                        });
                changeAppColorDialog.show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because themes don't change like that.  A theme has to be set before inflating the views.  Afterwards, the views will not be refreshed to a new theme.  However if you were to create a new View it would pick up the new theme.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base Activity for your app and override onCreate to set the theme. Derive all your other activities from this base Activity.

You can also check this particular tutorial (if you are doing activity theme):

http://mrbool.com/how-to-change-the-layout-theme-of-an-android-application/25837